# Хранение одиночных объектов в Django

Tags: django, хранение-данных

Задача стоит так: есть сайт на `Django`. Есть некоторые данные, которые можно представить одним объектом (гистограмма распределения некоторой величины, количество элементов гистограммы сравнительно небольшое). Эти данные изменяются сравнительно редко, а отображать их нужно часто, поэтому пересчитывать данные при каждом показе не хочется.

Вопрос в том, где такие данные лучше хранить с точки зрения идеологии `Django`?

Заводить таблицу в БД для одного объекта мне кажется не правильно.

Склоняюсь к тому, чтобы хранить этот объект в сериализованном виде в каком-нибудь файле, а при необходимости его читать и показывать на сайте, но может быть есть какой-нибудь рекомендованый способ хранения таких данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В одном своем проекте на `django` необходимо было хранить конфиги проекта в одном объекте. Использовал для этого [`singleton`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). В частности, проект [`django-solo`](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo).